# ConcurrentModificationException Map

Tags: java, spring, exception

Why i getting the `ConcurrentModificationException`. With this programming style it should not appear. Have i missing  something? I can't find any solution to that problem. This code is called every second with @Scheduled in Spring.

```
 Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, Integer> entry= iterator.next(); // this row throw the expection
        while (entry.getValue().compareTo(value) <= 0) {
        iterator.remove();
        }
      }
```

Comment: what kind of map is that? from javadocs of Iterator.remove() "The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method, unless an overriding class has specified a concurrent modification policy" Can it be, that remove was called before this error occured?

Comment: What is the underlying `Map` implementation? And, show a minimal example.

Comment: Hi & welcome! :wave The `CME` is sort of justified, and is in the implementation of the underlying set/iterator... Please workaround: 1. An additional "set" (`toRemove`, filling it in the loop, then using `removeAll(toRemove)` 2. if java >=8: `removeIf(lambda)` 3. Stream, filter, map, collect (https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrentmodificationexception) ...

Comment: its a LinkedHashMap and remove was not called

Comment: If this code is called every second, is it possible that you have two concurrent executions, on two different threads, on the same map?  Also, did you mean to use a `while` loop in the line `while (entry.getValue()...)`?  If this loop gets entered at all, it is an infinite loop which removes everything in the map after that point and eventually fails with an IllegalStateException when the iterator is exhausted.